# Pass parameter to another page to generate listview from Json

Tags: json, listview, jquery-mobile, geturl

Hello I'm using this js to pass the url parameter and it's working just fine, but my problem is that when I  define the path to the JSON file I don't want to use the id of the item...I want to use another Id. For example: I have the following item:

```
 {"id":"1",
"name":"Winery",
"street":"Chile",
"number":"898",
"phone":"4204040",
"mail":"winery@hotmail.com",
"web":"www.winery.com",
"lat":"-32.891638",
"long":"-68.846522",
"id_localidad":"1",
"id_provincia":"1"}
```

I want to put id_localidad at the end of the path, to generate the listview depending on the city (id_localidad is the id of the city where the shop is), not the id of the item. And this is not working for me.

Thanks in advance!

**JS FILE**

```
 $('#PuntosDeVenta').live('pageshow',function(event){


 var id =  getUrlVars()["id"];


 $.getJSON('http://localhost/CavaOnline/json_PuntosDeVentas.php?id_localidad='+id,  function(vinerias) {
 //THIS IS NOT WORKING, IS THE SAME AS PUTTING id, not id_localidad

 $.each(vinerias, function(index, vineria) {

    $('#listviewVinerias').append( '<li><a href="FichaTecnicaVineria.php?id=' + vineria[id - 1].id + '" > ' +
                '<img src="pics/' + vineria[id - 1].img_url1 + '"/>' +
                '<h4>' + vineria[id - 1].name+'</h4>' +
                '<p>' + vineria[id - 1].street+ ' ' + vineria[id - 1].number+ '</p>' +
                '</a></li>');

    $('#listviewVinerias').listview('refresh') 

  });

 });

});

function getUrlVars() {

var vars = [], hash;

var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');

for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)

{

    hash = hashes[i].split('=');

    vars.push(hash[0]);

    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];

}

return vars;

}
```

**Div where I load the List**

```
 <div data-role="content">

 <ul id="listviewVinerias" data-role="listview"></ul>

 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm assuming your `vinerias` is a variable containing a list of JSON objects, even though I don't know why you are calling `[id-1]` everywhere.
 If so, you can use the `.filter()` function to filter out the elements that have an id_localidad equal to the one specified.

```
var filteredVinerias = vinerias.filter(function(index){
    return this["id_localidad"] === "1" //The localidad you want
});
```